# What prevents windows from deleting a file that is in use?

Tags: windows, cmd, operating-system, delete-file

Sometimes I try to delete a file with `del /f filename`and it says "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.". Out of curiosity, what exactly is preventing this from happening? Is it the way that the hardware is set up, or is it more on the software side? And if the only thing preventing this from happening is the software, is there a way to work around it (force windows to delete part of the memory that is being accessed, and if it causes an error in whatever process is using it, just let it crash and exit)? Tried to look online and couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: The operating system stops it. No, there is no way to bypass that, either. That  would be pretty stupid to allow another program to delete a file that another process is currently using, just like it would be pretty stupid to be standing out on the branch of a tree and handing your partner behind  you a chain saw to use to cut that branch.

Comment: This is a Windows file API __feature__ which other operating systems don't have. A directory cannot be deleted on being the current directory of a running process which is usually the program files directory of the process. A file cannot be deleted on being opened by an application which opened it without using [no sharing restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfile-class) (see `CFile::shareDenyNone`). The default is `shareExclusive` independent on which function is used by an application running on Windows to open a file like `fopen` (C example).

Comment: Windows uses a cooperative data-access model that requires every file open that requests data access (i.e. read/execute, write/append, or delete/rename) to declare whether sharing read, write, or delete access is allowed. If a previous open has data access that you're not willing to share, or if a previous open isn't willing to share the access that you're requesting, then the open fails as a sharing violation (error 32).

Comment: If delete access is shared, a file can be renamed or deleted. But note that with a traditional Windows delete, a file won't be unlinked until all handles are closed. Windows 10 also supports a Unix-style delete with NTFS, for which a file is immediately unlinked from the directory even if it has existing handles. (It actually gets relinked to a reserved NTFS system directory, but it's out of the way.) `DeleteFileW` in Windows 10 has been updated to try a Unix-style delete. This will help alleviate asynchronous behavior due to malware scanners and such that's common with the classic delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programs utilize a file, they maintain ["file handles"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-handles) which provide references to the file & context for the program to interact. While these handles don't always prevent actions, like deleting, the OS will block these actions if a program's file handle tells it to. What you're experiencing is when these handles fail to be closed when a program should have released it.

The [Handle tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle), a part of the Windows [Sysinternals suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) by Mark Russinovich, is a command-line interface for viewing & managing these stuck file handles. It's not the simplest tool to use, being quite barebones, but it is powerful. Given the CLI nature, one can certainly wrap additional functionality for ease of use. Here's [a (rough) example](https://github.com/CAndRyan/PoShTools/blob/master/Functions/Handle.psm1) in PowerShell.

*EDIT: **Use with caution**. To clarify, forcing file handles to close can lead to data corruption and should only be used if you're certain the handles are stuck; e.g., when you explicitly open in a program that you also closed. It is far safer to restart your machine, if possible.*

Answer (score -1):

If a software program is loading or reading the file you want to delete, then this error appears.
And the only thing you can do, is closing the program and then try to delete the file again..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Worse, it's also wrong. See the documentation for [CreateFileW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) (specifically the `dwShareMode` parameter). There are many ways to allow a file to be deleted, even when in use, and there are many ways to prevent a file from being deleted, even when it isn't strictly in use.